# Meaning of "~/page.aspx"

Tags: asp.net

I am a new comer in asp.net world. Just starting my first project in asp.net. I have seen the following code in several examples -

```
<a href="~/folder/page.aspx">A Link</a>
```

What is the usage of "~" symbol here?

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the root of your application.

Most of the time you run your application on the full domain so you could refer to `~/` and it would mean `http://www.example.com/` but you could also set up a forum which would be set as an application all of its own in `/forum/` then if you said `~/` in there it would mean `http://www.example.com/forum/`.

Answer (score 1):

Its means in root of your application. rest part represent, there is one folder, with name `folder` and this folder contains `page.aspx`

Comment: Can i use <a href="~/folder/pageA.aspx">Page A</a> in Page B or <a href="~/folder/pageB.aspx">Page B</a> in Page A?

Comment: It is depend on your requirement. You can do